# linux date -- increment current date by minutes but prevent overflow (rollover past midnight)

Tags: linux, bash, shell

So I'm trying to get a date, 1 minute into the future, but not allow midnight rollover, e.g.

```
date -d "23:58:42 300 seconds" +%H:%M:%S
```

returns "00:03:42", however I want it to be capped at "23:59:59".
Any ideas how?

Comment: Do the answers below return what you expect? If  not, can you please give further information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

300 seconds is not a minute, but, the easiest way would be a simple script:

```
#!/bin/bash
t="$1"
interval="$2"

h=$(date -d "$t $interval seconds" +%H)
if [ "$h" = "00" ] ; then
    echo "23:59:59"
else
    date -d "$t $interval seconds" +%H:%M:%S
fi
```

This works well if your interval is under an hour.

Answer (score 1):

Try it with the following script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

secsToAdd=300
addendTime="23:58:42"

resultTime=$(date -d "$addendTime $secsToAdd seconds" +%H:%M:%S);
midnightTime="23:59:59"

addendTimeSeconds=$(echo "$addendTime" | awk -F: '{ print ($1 * 3600) + ($2 * 60) + $3 }');
midnightTimeSeconds=$(echo "$midnightTime" | awk -F: '{ print ($1 * 3600) + ($2 * 60) + $3 }');

if [[ "$secsToAdd" -gt $((midnightTimeSeconds-addendTimeSeconds)) ]]
then
    echo "$midnightTime"
else 
    echo "$resultTime"
fi
```

**Logic**:

If `Seconds to add > Midnight time - Addend time` -> you have overflow.

*(It works regardless of how big the seconds to be added are).*